# Change to different icloud account on iOS9

Tags: ipad, icloud, ios, accounts

I've configured an iPad with an iCloud account that I don't want to use anymore. I've changed the iTunes and App Store account to the right one. Now I want to change the iCloud account as well. I can logout, but don't know how to change the email address or account name.

**How can I change the account I use for iCloud?**

Comment: You cannot truly 'abandon' an iCloud account without also abandoning anything purchased through it or registered to it. If the device was registered to that account, then that's the account it will always belong to, unless you wipe it & start fresh on the new account, giving up all purchases made under the old one; or by swapping accounts every time you wish to access any OS or app updates on the old account.

Comment: I have not bought anything through that account. So I truly need to wipe the iPad completely to get rid of it?

Comment: You can change the primary email address. I'm sure it would be far simpler - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202667